How to test the type of a class without a public constructor?
I have a statement in my tests:
    expect(DynamoDBClient).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.any(DynamoDBDocumentClient),
      { tableName: 'histories-table', indexPartitionKeyName: 'id' },
    )

If I attempt to run the test, I get an error
Cannot assign a 'protected' constructor type to a 'public' constructor type.
It seems to me that because DynamoDBDocumentClient doesn't have a public type that the expect.any() does not work with it.  Just wondering if there is a straight forward fix for this.

Not my class, the DynamoDBDocumentClient from @aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb
